# Why is my keyboard not detected after restart?

Tags: windows-10, usb, keyboard, desktop-computer

I have a new PC build with `I-3 7100 Processes`, `GA-H110M-H DDR4` Motherboard, and `GT110 2 GB` GPU. I also bought a new Keyboard (It's a cheap one) Tech-Com `TTPL KB-915 USB`.

Whenever I shutdown my computer and power off, after I restart the PC it doesn't detect the keyboard. I have to unplug the USB Keyboard and plug it in again for Windows 10 to detect it.

Answer (score -2):

Check if the keyboard appear in the Device Manager after restart.

If it doesn't appear there. it's most probably the poor contact issue between the USB port and keyboard cable. switch another port or replace a keyboard cable.

In addition, update the keyboard driver to the latest one.

Comment: It doesn't appear in Device Manager. When I unplug and plug again, PC detects it and it's shown there. Just curious, if this is the cable issue, why does it works on plugging again? Drivers are up to date.

Comment: It clearly isn't a port or cable problem as the keyboard is recognised if it is unplugged and plugged in again as stated in the question.

Comment: You can try to update its driver. Meanwhile, connect other USB device, like mouse via the same port to restart to see the result.